# How to use Service provider Notifications in android?

Tags: android, mobile, notifications, provider

I m new to android development.

I want to develop an application which store all the information given by a service provider.

I mean to say, when we complete call/message any service for that matter, our service provider sends us a notification kind of thing to our mobile phone.

I want to capture that data and store in phone and intimate the user about the used services cost and validity.

We may also put an alarm to the user informing that he is going to complete his validity period with in xdays or so.

Please let me know if there are any such methods/classes in Android API.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what kind of notification do they send? Through what channel do they send SMS/Telephony/Socket?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need notifications to be sent in real time to the phone?

If not, consider polling your server that is by far the simplest solution for notifications. You can use the BuzzBox SDK to scheduler a recurring task pretty easily and to create a notification when the server has new stuff.
Read more: http://hub.buzzbox.com/android-sdk/

If your service already has an rss feed things are even easier with the rss reader integrated in the buzzbox api..